# ASP.NET populate multi-select dropdown list from other without external click event

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, drop-down-menu, modalpopupextender

I implemented the Multi-select dropdownlist using [Bootstrap-style-DropDownList-example-in-ASPNet](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Bootstrap-style-DropDownList-example-in-ASPNet.aspx) as referernce.

I have the below concerns

1. In single-select dropdownlist we can use the event **onSelectIndexChanged** to populate other dropdownlist control without using any button. But I have 5 or more such dropdowns. Consider there is a multi-select dropdownlist for countries and I select US and Canada, the next dropdownlist should list all the states in these selected countries. what event should I use for multi-select list? I don't want to click Submit every time to capture the selected values. What is the best way to achieve this? *Similar to SSRS linked Parameters*.
2. When I use script manager, after postback event the multi-select dropdown goes to list-box. How to retain the css even after postback?

[image: Before post-back] [image: After postback]

How to resolve these issues?

Comment: If you have used `asp:DropDownList` then you should do this in `SelectedIndexChanged` event.

Comment: @MairajAhmad - DropDownList doesn't allow me to have multi-select in it. and for each select the `selectedIndexChanged` is triggered.